# People app disappeared from apps on Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, system-apps, people-app

It's a system app, but somehow I disabled it. Now, it won't show me my contacts or anything. If I try to see a missed call from notification drawer, it leaves me at home screen. I cannot view any of my call records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by clicking reset app preference from the action bar in Settings

Answer (score 0):

Enable the app you disabled by following the following steps:

1. Go into the main system settings.
2. Open your main Settings menu Tap
3. on Apps Swipe to “All” Find the app you disabled and click on it
4. In the top right you will see a enable button. Press that button to
   enable it.

Comment: The button cant be selected. :(